# Lingering Injury and Speed

Tags: dnd-5e, feats

One of the characters in my party lost her foot to a Kobold. I am using the rules that any character that is knocked down gets a lingering injury as per the Dungeon Masters Guide PG 272. Her character being a halfling, her new speed is 12.5 feet (rounded to 13) now that she has a peg leg.

She is debating either taking the feat "mobility" which increases speed by 10ft or perhaps even two levels of monk for the same effect.

The question is, would she get 10 extra feet of movement with the feat (going to 23ft) or would the new speed also be halved and take her new speed to 18ft?

Comment: Note that you've been nice to give 13 and not 12. The rule clearly says you are expected to round down...

Comment: Perhaps a mistake from starting with 4th edition. Honestly half a foot will not matter much in practice

Answer (score 20, accepted):

While it's not entirely clear, I would assume that the 10 feet is added to her speed, then her speed is halved. Points to consider:

- Both the Monk bonus and the bonus from Mobility are permanent bonuses, whereas the Lingering Injury is meant to be a temporary penalty (lasts until you get a *regenerate* spell cast on you).
- If she already had the bonus to her speed *before* she lost a leg, you probably wouldn't even have thought to ask this question.
- There's no distinction between "base speed" and "bonus speed" or anything like that. Every character has a speed, which the Monk bonus and Mobility both increase, and the Lingering Injury halves.

Now, it must be said: I would strongly advise her not to invest in 2 levels of Monk or the Mobility feat unless she was going to anyway. She's looking at a huge, permanent investment of extremely scarce resources which probably won't contribute to her overall character much at all. In exchange for which, she's going to slightly mitigate (not even remove) a temporary penalty.

*Regenerate* is a 7th-level spell available to Bards, Druids, and Clerics. I'm guessing there's no one in her party capable of casting it (or they would've fixed her already), but it shouldn't be infeasible for her party to go looking for someone who can. Alternatively, they can go shopping for a scroll of *regenerate* (assuming they have one of the above classes in the party).

Obviously, as the DM, you hold the choice as to whether they can find a caster or scroll to help her (or not), how difficult it will be, and how much it will cost. That said, I really recommend making this possible. For the player in question, it will allow her to fix her character without having to take levels or feats she doesn't really want to; for you and the rest of the group, it's a great opportunity for a sidequest.

Comment: The second bullet point really is a good one, IMO. You might also point out the similarity in reasoning to how damage resistance is applied with respect to bonuses to damage. +1